# Dynamically update form_list to point to some subclass(known at run time only) for a step, and render that form

Tags: django, python-3.x, wizard, django-formtools

I have a scenerio where the forms to be used for steps are known at runtime only. Currently, `form_list` is static for every `step`. But in the updated requirements, Each `step` has some runtime logic to determine the corresponding `form_class`. I was thinking of a way to update the `form_list` dynamically.

I have tried overriding get_form_list, which uses the runtime logic to determine the form, and modifies form_list accordingly.

**urls.py**

```
named_forms = views.FormView.form_list

contact_wizard = views.FormView.as_view(named_forms,
                                                url_name=<the url name>,
                                                done_step_name='finished')

url-patterns = [
    path('path', contact_wizard, name='form1')
]
```

**Wizard**

```
class FormView(NamedUrlSessionWizardView,):
    form_list = (                           //static one
        ("step-one", FormStepOne),
        ("step-two", FormStepTwo),
        ("step-three", FormStepThree),
    )

    def get_form_list(self):          //updates form_list according to some logic
        self.form_list = OrderedDict()
        self.form_list["step-one"] = 
            self.integration_class.step_one_form_class
        self.form_list["step-two"] = 
            self.integration_class.step_two_form_class
        self.form_list["step-three"] = 
            self.integration_class.step_three_form_class
        return super().get_form_list()
```

Form_list is getting updated correctly,but the form is not getting rendered according to the new form-list.
Rendered form is getting picked up from old static form_list only.

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this?

Comment: @intelis yeah. I have overriden the method `get_form` instead of `get_form_list`


`def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        self.form_list = OrderedDict()
        self.form_list["step-one"] = 
            self.integration_class.step_one_form_class
        self.form_list["step-two"] = 
            self.integration_class.step_two_form_class
        self.form_list["step-three"] = 
            self.integration_class.step_three_form_class
        form = super(FormView, self).get_form(step, data, files)
        return form
`

Comment: Thanks! So doing it this way works correctly for you? validation and all?